# how to retrieve the key of added_child

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function:

```
myRef.on("child_added", function(data){
    var keys = Object.keys(data.val());
}
```

That only gives me the keys of objects inside the child.

E.g. structure:

```
children = {
  added_child1:{
    'name':'child1'
  },
  added_child2:{
    'name':'child2'
  }
}
```

myRef links to children. 
How to get the key of newly added_child?

Comment: Can you provide what your data structure looks like? At the moment, I'm not sure many people understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I've edited my question. Is this any clearer?

Comment: Do you want to get keys for the child that got added instead of all the keys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data.key` to get the key of the newly added child, example:

```
var myRef = firebase.database().ref('children');
myRef.on("child_added", function(data){
   var key  = data.key;
   var keys = Object.keys(data.val());
}
```

`data.key` will retrieve the `added_child2`